# How to inclue page in tabed panel in anugalr JS?

Tags: angularjs, include

I am developing one web site where I need to include page in page in tabbed panel using following code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Bootstrap tab panel with Angular</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 1}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(1)">Heat Map</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 2}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(2)">Grouped Data</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 3}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(3)">Three</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div ng-class="{'tab-pane active': activeTab === 1, 'tab-pane' : activeTab !== 1}"><div ng-inlcude='"samplepage.html"'></div></div>
        <div ng-class="{'tab-pane active': activeTab === 2, 'tab-pane' : activeTab !== 2}">Panel 2 Content</div>
        <div ng-class="{'tab-pane active': activeTab === 3, 'tab-pane' : activeTab !== 3}">Panel 3 Content</div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        angular.module("app", [])
            .controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.activeTab = 1;

                $scope.setActiveTab = function(tabToSet) {
                    $scope.activeTab = tabToSet;
                }
            }]);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**samplepage.html**

```
<html><head></head><body>Hello World!</body></html>
```

But when I click on tab, page does not get included. How can I fix such issue?

Answer (score 1):

try this.you should put **`template`** in ***`src`***.

```
 <div ng-include src="'samplepage.html'"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-inlcude='"samplepage.html"'>
```

you're typing error

```
<div ng-include='"samplepage.html"'>
```

Comment: Please see working http://plnkr.co/edit/X2bm8oJsp66vXhTwUs2u. It contains copy of your listings with corrected typing error mentioned above.

Comment: ng-include only use able same domain page,  ng-include using XHRRequest , and XHRRequest has SOP ( same origin policy ) , and check  path